# Bulk rename files using bash

Tags: rename

I need to bulk rename files changing `.-.` to `.`

goal: `file.-.txt` is now `file.txt`

```
rename 's/.-./.' *.txt
```

Doesn't work.  What's wrong?

Comment: No messages or output from the command: rename 's/.-././' *.txt

Comment: also, both `.`s in the search string needs to be escaped as `\.`, otherwise they will match **any** character, not a literal `.`.   perl rename uses regex matching.  `s/\.-\././g'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'll agree with @roaima is probably not one of the `perl`-based variants, with the  perl-based variants, the syntax for that would be:

```
rename 's/\.(-\.)+/./g' ./*.txt
```

To replace all the occurrences of `.-.` with `.` in all the (non-hidden) file names that end in `.txt`. That would rename `-a-b.-.-.c.-.-.txt` with `-a-b.c.txt` for instance.

`s/.-././g` would rename it to `-..-.c.-.txt` as `.` is a regexp operator that matches any character and needs to be  escaped so it matches a literal `.`.

`s/\.-\././g` would rename it to `-a-b.-.c.-.txt`.

And of course the important `./` prefix without which you introduce command injection vulnerabilities in some variants of `rename`.

For all kind of renaming, I prefer `zsh`'s `zmv` as it doesn't have most of the problems and incompatibilities with all the `rename` variants and does some sanity checks before hand.

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv '*.txt' '${f//.(-.)##/.}'
```

Or

```
zmv '(*).-(.txt)' '$1$2'
```

To only replace the `-.-` before `txt` with `.`.

Comment: Thanks! zmv did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the perl version of `rename`, because if you were you would have received the error `Substitution replacement not terminated at (eval 1) line 1.` due to the missing trailing `/` in the substitution expresssion.

Therefore, you need to use the syntax for the ["other" `rename`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html)

```
rename -vn -- '.-.' '.' *.txt
```

In this specific instance you don't really need to quote the source and destination patterns as they don't have shell glob characters (`*`, etc.), but it's good practice so I've done it here anyway.

Remove either or both `-v` (verbose) and `-n` (no action) when you're happy you've got something that works for your situation. Add the `-a` option to replace `a`ll the occurrences of `.-.` with `.`, for instance, to rename `foo.-.bar.-.txt` to `foo.bar.txt` instead of `foo.bar.-.txt` (beware it would still rename `file.-.-.txt` to `file.-.txt`) or `-l` to replace the `l`ast occurrence.

For the curious, the `rename` command took `s/.-./.` (yes, those literal seven characters) as the source pattern and the first matching filename from the `*.txt` glob as the destination pattern. It then tried to match the source pattern against each of the remaining files from the `*.txt` glob. Obviously this would have failed to match any, and because there was no syntactic error no message was output.

Answer (score -1):

What is wrong with `rename 's/.-./.' *.txt`

1. Your s-command is not closed. Add a `/` at the back
2. As roaima sais, dash '-' does not match underscore '_'

Comment: typo on my part the pattern is .-.  not ._.